# PDO login keeps showing false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello im working on a basic login script with php. For not im not worried about security i just want it to work. But for some reason it keeps returning false when in the database the values are there.

Edit: connection.php contains the information to login to the database.

```
$config['db'] = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname' => 'mywebsite'
);




$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host']. ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'] , $config['db']['username'] , $config['db']['password']);
```

end of connection.php

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{

    require_once 'Connection.php';
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];


        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT `username` , `password` from `library` where `username`  = ? And `password` = ? ');

        $sth->bindParam(1, $user);
        $sth->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $sth->execute();

        if($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            echo $user;
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?  For example ill send in test for user and 123 for password. Which  exists in my library and it returns false.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected?

Comment: Most def. I used the connection.php for a register script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use delimiters for columns name:

```
SELECT username, password FROM `library` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
```

also your `if` test is wrong. [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) never returns a integral value therefore you need to change:

```
if($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) {
```

to:

```
if($sth->fetchColumn() != false) {
```

Comment: what do you mean and you explain?

Comment: Thank you , it seems the stackoverflow answer in another question was wrong then.  Can u you explain to me the delimiters. When i view some people's sql statements some use delimiters on all the rows and cols. And some dont.

Comment: @Dahnny012, In certain extensions (like Mysql) you can use delimiters for table names, but that's just it. If you can, don't use them. The rule of thumb is: don't use delimiters unless you must.